# open source mail clients in java

Tags: java, email, pop3

Are there any open source email clients in java that you can recommend?

Something that pulls in emails via pop, sends emails, stores sent emails, etc.
Similar to what mozilla thunderbird does, but on build using jsp etc. for the web.

(preferably web based, but would also be interested in desktop apps)

Answer (score 1):

I can point you at [Davmail](http://davmail.sourceforge.net/), its not a java smtp server or a desktop client, but its an outlook gateway that implements itself as a smtp/pop3 server. So you can put Thunderbird on your desktop and use it (via davmail) to access Exchange.

Works really well, but the code is available if you want to see some smtp/pop3/emaily-type code.